# In Github Desktop, in Repository Settings, can I safely switch back and forth between To Contribute To The Parent Repository and For My Own Purposes?

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

While working on my own project in my fork I sometimes come across improvements that would also benefit the parent project.

I want to know if I can safely switch back and forth between ‘To contribute to the parent repository’ and ‘For my own purposes’? in Github Desktop's Repository Settings. This in order to switch between pushing to my own fork (most times) and creating pull requests for the parent project (some times).

The idea is to switch to ‘To contribute to the parent repository’, make a branch based on the parent, make the improvements, and create a pull request for the parent project. Then switch back to ‘For my own purposes’ and pick one of my fork-based branches and continue working on my own project.

So, in Github Desktop, in Repository Settings, can I safely switch back and forth between ‘To contribute to the parent repository’ and ‘For my own purposes’? Or am I just supposed to pick one and leave it like that?

Answer (score 0):

ok it's simple :
Repository settings>fork behavior>for my own purpose
but after switching, pushing will still affect the original repository...
that pushed commits made before I switch though.
Apparently, not.... it looks like PR branch is definitely linked to the original repository

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).